# Google App Script Adding one Day to a date

Tags: javascript, datetime, google-apps-script

I can't figure out how to add one day to a date in Google App Script. I have this script:

```
function dateTest() {

var testDate = new Date();
var secondDate = new Date(testDate.getDate()+1);

 Logger.log(testDate);
 Logger.log(secondDate);
}
```

Which produces the following log:

[16-11-30 16:35:02:499 GMT] Wed Nov 30 16:35:02 GMT+00:00 2016

[16-11-30 16:35:02:500 GMT] Thu Jan 01 01:00:00 GMT+01:00 1970

I don't understand why it's not adding to the date?

Comment: Related: [Add days to JavaScript Date](https://stackoverflow.com/q/563406/1595451)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Change it to:

```
var testDate = new Date();
var secondDate = new Date();
secondDate.setDate(testDate.getDate()+1);
```

This should keep the day good for daylight savings time changes and leap year as well.

Comment: Thanks, I like the simplicity of this answer

Comment: There is a potential gotcha here to keep in mind, depending what you're using this for.  `getDate` gets the day of the month, i.e. today is "14", not Feb 14, 2020.  If you're using this to compare dates you could have an issue. For example, if you want to know, is today's date greater than X date?  Both 2/1/2020 and 4/1/2020 would return true because 14 > 1.

Answer (score 10):

`getDate()` gets the day of the month. If you are passing a number to the Date constructor in `new Date(value)`, it expects that number to be the number of milliseconds since the Unix epoch, see [Date on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date). So you're adding 31ms (today) to the unix epoch, hence the date is 01 Jan 1970 and a little bit.

To add one day try:

```
var secondDate = new Date(testDate.getTime() + 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
```

This adds the milliseconds in one day to `testDate` and creates a new Date from it.

`getTime()` gets the representation of a date in milliseconds since the Unix epoch, so by adding the number of ms in one day to it, you can create a new Date that is +1 day.

Comment: Great, thanks for the explanation. I prefer the second answer for it's simplicity though. Appreciate your time.

Comment: Not a good approach as in places where daylight saving is observed, days are not always 24 hours long.

Answer (score 6):

You could also say:

```
var tomorrow = new Date(Date.now() + 1000*60*60*24)
```

Comment: This does work, but I prefer the second answer. Appreciate the response though!

Comment: Not a good approach as in places where daylight saving is observed, days are not always 24 hours long.

Comment: Does the Date class know about this? How does it know what time zone I am in, and can I force it to use UTC?