# GoogleScript concatenate Date calculation instead of adding days

Tags: javascript, date, google-apps-script

I have a problem with Google Script. I am trying to calculate all dates of a week. I have the Monday Value in a sheet and copy it to an array and then declare it as a variable. I can afterwards format it and extract the week, the year and so on.

However, if I want to add one day for Tuesday he is giving me the Monday Date and adding a 1 at the end.

I am using the following code:

```
var StartDatum = Data [5][7]
var Week = Utilities.formatDate(StartDatum, "GMT", "ww")-1;
var Month =Utilities.formatDate(StartDatum, "GMT", "MM");

for (var i=14; i < 21; i++){
var Datum = ((StartDatum + (i - 14)));
}
```

For StartDatum I receive a proper date:

```
Mon Jan 13 2020 09:00:00 GMT+0100 (CET)
```

Week and Month also work.

But for Datum I receive:

```
Mon Jan 13 2020 09:00:00 GMT+0100 (CET)0
Mon Jan 13 2020 09:00:00 GMT+0100 (CET)1
Mon Jan 13 2020 09:00:00 GMT+0100 (CET)2
Mon Jan 13 2020 09:00:00 GMT+0100 (CET)3
```

... and so one.

Could somebody please give me a hint about my mistake

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Google App Script Adding one Day to a date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40893620/google-app-script-adding-one-day-to-a-date)

Comment: It seems the `+` in `StartDatum + ` is treated as string concatenation, so *StartDatum* is converted to a string. Then the result of `(i - 14)` is appended as a string too. You can't add a day to a Date object by just adding 1.

Comment: PS In javascript, variables starting with a capital letter are, by convention, reserved for constructors so *startDatum*, *datum*, etc. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When performing date manipulations, you need to use [the `get...()` and `set...()` methods of the `Date` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date).

Here's an example of starting with today's date and manipulating the `Date` object to depict the days of the following two weeks (which also happens to demonstrate clean handling of month boundaries):

**Code:**

```
function dateManipulationExample() {
  var timestamp = new Date();
  Logger.log('Starting date: ' + Utilities.formatDate(timestamp, 'UTC', 'yyyy-MM-dd'));

  for (var i = 1; i <= 14; i++) {
    timestamp.setDate(timestamp.getDate() + 1);
    Logger.log(i + ' day(s) later: ' + Utilities.formatDate(timestamp, 'UTC', 'yyyy-MM-dd'));
  }
}
```

**Logging output**:

```
[20-01-21 14:34:17:065 PST] Starting date: 2020-01-21
[20-01-21 14:34:17:066 PST] 1 day(s) later: 2020-01-22
[20-01-21 14:34:17:067 PST] 2 day(s) later: 2020-01-23
[20-01-21 14:34:17:067 PST] 3 day(s) later: 2020-01-24
[20-01-21 14:34:17:068 PST] 4 day(s) later: 2020-01-25
[20-01-21 14:34:17:068 PST] 5 day(s) later: 2020-01-26
[20-01-21 14:34:17:069 PST] 6 day(s) later: 2020-01-27
[20-01-21 14:34:17:070 PST] 7 day(s) later: 2020-01-28
[20-01-21 14:34:17:070 PST] 8 day(s) later: 2020-01-29
[20-01-21 14:34:17:071 PST] 9 day(s) later: 2020-01-30
[20-01-21 14:34:17:072 PST] 10 day(s) later: 2020-01-31
[20-01-21 14:34:17:072 PST] 11 day(s) later: 2020-02-01
[20-01-21 14:34:17:073 PST] 12 day(s) later: 2020-02-02
[20-01-21 14:34:17:073 PST] 13 day(s) later: 2020-02-03
[20-01-21 14:34:17:074 PST] 14 day(s) later: 2020-02-04
```

For reference, [date math is briefly discussed in the Apps Script documentation](https://developers.google.com/google-ads/scripts/docs/features/dates#date_math).

Comment: Setting the offset to UTC may have unexpected results early in the day for users with a positive timezone offset and late in the day for those with a negative offset.

Comment: Hello chuckx thank you for the code. I adapted mine based on your proposal and it worked.